# Is there anyway to skip `Reindexing in Elastic Search with database

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elastic-stack, reindex

Currently working with a large database that typically takes 2-3 days to reindex completely, and I only need to add a new field to the mapping for a specific table.

1. What could be a possible solution to skip reindexing?
2. What is the possible way to do it in minimum time?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new field to the index does not require full re-indexing. You can use the Bulk APIs update operation to populate the data for new field

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment but can you explain how it gone a work in my scenario. Like by only updating it will  create the new mapping as well for required field.?